# Помогите исправить ошибки в программе, строящей параболу

Tags: python

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *:
>   'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'

Выдаётся данная ошибка при запуске следующей программы:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                           AutoMinorLocator)
    import numpy as np

    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

    print ('Введите а')
    a=input
    print ('Введите b')        
    b=input
    print ('Введите c')
    c=input
    y=a*x*x + b*x + c  

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
    ax.set_title("Графики квадратичной функции: y=ax^2+bx+c", fontsize=16)
    ax.set_xlabel("x", fontsize=14)        
    ax.set_ylabel("y", fontsize=14)
    ax.grid(which="major", linewidth=1.2)
    ax.grid(which="minor", linestyle="--", color="black", linewidth=0.5)
    ax.plot(x, y, label="y = ax^2+bx+c")
    ax.legend()
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator   (AutoMinorLocator())
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator   (AutoMinorLocator())
    ax.tick_params(which='major', length=10, width=2)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=5, width=1)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Откуда вы взяли этот код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неверно осуществлен ввод переменной

надо вот так

```
a = float(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости Вы допустили ошибку в том, что вместо того чтобы положить в переменные a, b и c то, что возвращает input, вы положили саму функцию.

Поэтому он ругается что не может умножить функцию.

Решение:

Измените с этого:

```
a = input
```

На это:

```
a = input()
```

Скобочки в конце означают что Вы вызвали функию, и положили то что она возвращает в переменную a (так нужно с каждым `input`).

Также не забудьте что `input` возвращает строку а не число. Чтобы получить число, оберните эту функцию в `int()` или `float()`